# Is there any way to allow objects only to move within another objects in a canvas in fabric js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I'm new to fabric js, Simply I want to allow some objects (rectangles) to move within a given object(polygon) as in the diagram. Is there any way to do it in fabric js?

[image: diagram]